# OnClick function - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code while sending two parameters through onclick event i am getting a error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

```
  html += "<td class='" + className + "'><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#tourRequModal' onclick='dateSel(" + Date + "|" + priceArr[i] + ")'>" + i + priceText + "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Inspect the generated markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here using Date alone causes the problem so Write it as:

```
html += "<td class='" + className + "'><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#tourRequModal' onclick='dateSel(\"" + new Date().toString() + "\"," + priceArr[i] + ")'>" + i + priceText + "</a></td>";
```