# <div> onclick Uncaught SyntaxError?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, append, syntax-error

I give a link to the div and when I click it gives this error."İd" pulls its value from the database.it works when you write the link to the browser in this way.

> www.site.com/form.html?id=1

But when I click the div does not work.Don't want to use "a href".Because it disrupts the structure of the div I use.

```
$("#demo").append("<div class='item' onclick='location.href=form.html?id="+id+"'>"+title+"</div>");
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnClick function - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177916/onclick-function-uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#demo").append("<div class='item' onclick='location.href=\"form.html?id="+id+"\"'>"+title+"</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes arround the 'form.html....' part, because it is a string. In your case you need to use escaped quotes:

```
$("#demo").append("<div class='item' onclick='location.href=\"form.html?id="+id+"\";'>"+title+"</div>");
```

Comment: sorry i made a little error, i used single quotes but needed double escaped quotes! I edited.

Comment: Yes, @Maksym Petrenko wrote code worked.But works in your code.